# как выставить разрешение на рабочем столе (windows 7) 1270х710?

Tags: windows

как выставить разрешение на рабочем столе (windows 7) 1270х710 ?

Comment: Ну вообще-то почти никак - либо драйвер, либо монитор (а скорее всего оба) такое не поддерживают. А зачем? PS. Надо такие "дикие" разрешения - ставьте виртуальную машину.

Comment: я как-то уменьшал. Давно. Все было норм. Тут видеокарта заглючила, поставил другую, потом старую. И вот настройки слетели.  Зачем это надо - на рабочем столе на 4-10 пикселей рабочий стол выходи за границы видимой части телевизора. Например кнопка "пуск" на половину  видна по длине.

Comment: Просто установил драйвер видеокарты. Там есть уменьшение  размера  ,если рабочий стол не вписывается в экран дисплея. Там уменьшил на 40 пикселей. Все норм.

Answer (score 1):

[AMD](https://www.amd.com/ru/support/kb/faq/dh-032)

Nvidia:

1. Запустить Панель управления Nvidia
2. Дисплей -> Изменение разрешения -> Добавить разрешения... -> Создать своё разрешение
3. Задать нужные Вам параметры, протестировать их и добавить его в список для выбора
4. Выбрать его и использовать.

Answer (score 0):

***Запустить Панель управления Nvidia
Дисплей -> Изменение разрешения -> Добавить разрешения... -> Создать своё разрешение
Задать нужные Вам параметры, протестировать их и добавить его в список для выбора
Выбрать его и использовать.

> ---